# Efficient sorting of multiple vectors with respect to one vector?

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a 2D vector, `S`, and a 1D vector, `I`. Both `S` and `I` contain integers. Here is an example:

```
vector<int> I={6,2,3,1,4,5,0};
vector<vector<int>> S;
S[0]={0,1,3};
S[1]={1,2,4};
S[2]={4,5,6};
S[3]={0,3,5};
```

`I` contains numbers `0..n` and vectors `S` are all subsets of `I`. I want to sort items in vectors `S`, with respect to the order of items in `I`. So that:

```
S[0]={3,1,0};
S[1]={2,1,4};
S[2]={6,4,5};
S[3]={3,5,0};
```

My real vectors are large in size, so I need to do it in the most efficient way (in c++).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can populate a map of weights used for the sorting and then provide a custom comparator for sort:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> I={6,2,3,1,4,5,0};
    std::unordered_map<int,unsigned> weights;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < I.size(); ++i) weights[I[i]] = i;

    std::vector<int> s{3,6,5};
    std::sort(s.begin(),s.end(), [&weights](int a,int b){
        return weights[a] < weights[b];
    });

    for (const auto& e : s) std::cout << e << " ";
}
```

To sort many vectors you just need to call `sort` in a loop. If the numbers in `I` are always consecutive with no holes in between then using an array as look up table would be more efficient.